# after ajax post, GET isn't working node js

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax

So, after my ajax is firing up I get a value that I need in server side.

```
  $('.MyForm').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var createVar = $(this).find(".lessonText").html();

    $.ajax({
      url: '/qVal',
      method: 'post',
      dataType: 'text',
      data: {'desc':createVar},
      async: true,
      success: function(data){

      }
    })


  });
```

Here I am assigning to a variable and now I want to redirect from that point to another page.

```
router.post('/qVal', function(req,res){  
    SSN3 =req.session;
    SSN3.description = req.body.desc; 
    console.log(SSN3.description);
    return res.redirect('/questions');

});

router.get('/questions', function(req,res, next){
    res.render('questions');    
});
```

I know that I can redirect to another page by using `window.location.href` after ajax function is success but I want to do that from server side. The weirdest part that after post, get is firing up but it doesn't work. https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoUJ2.png

Comment: If you want to redirect you shouldn't be using AJAX in the first place. The whole point of AJAX is that the browser stays on the same page and makes async calls to the server.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are forgetting an extension in the url like .php or something like that.

```
 $('.MyForm').on('submit', function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var createVar = $(this).find(".lessonText").html();

$.ajax({
  url: '/qVal',  // <<--here
  method: 'post',
  dataType: 'text',
  data: {'desc':createVar},
  async: true,
  success: function(data){

  }
})


});
```

Comment: This is post url, which is working, then I want to use get to refirect to another page, but it doesn't work